# Partial update of device local buffer in Vulkan

Tags: vulkan

I'm generating vertex data to memory (from voxel data), setting up a staging buffer (host visible) (`vkCreateBuffer`), copying vertex data into staging buffer, setting up a device local buffer (`vkCreateBuffer`) and copy the buffer from host visible to device local (`vkCmdCopyBuffer`).

From what I understand there is a limit to how many buffers I can have, so I probably can't create one buffer per model.

For static models this is fine, just mash them together and upload. But I want to modify a few random vertexes "regularly". For this I'm thinking of doing differential update of device local buffers. So in a big buffer I only update the data that actually changed. Can this be done?

If I don't render anything from host visible buffer then it will not take up any resources on GPU? So I could keep the host visible buffers and don't have to recreate and fill them?

Comment: There's no limit to the number of buffers you can create for an application. But there's a limit to a number of memory allocations. See `VkPhysicalDeviceLimits::maxMemoryAllocationCount`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should be able to do what you want. Essentially you are sending your updated data *without* a staging buffer and copy command (similar to how we generally populate uniform buffers for example).

In psuedo-code:

- update the data in your application
- map the buffer
- copy the changed data
- unmap the buffer
- synchronize

The last part if the tricky aspect - you could simply make the buffer `VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_COHERENT_BIT` which means it will be updated before the *next* call to `vkQueueSubmit`. So basically you would want to do the above before the next frame is rendered, see [spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0/html/vkspec.html#synchronization-submission-host-writes).  Note that the buffer will need to be `VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT`.

Whether you make this 'dynamic' data part of your uber-buffer or a completely separate buffer is up to you.

This approach is used for things like particle systems that are managed by the application. Obviously copying directly to a buffer that is visible to both the host and the GPU is (presumably) slower than the staging/copy approach.

If however you want to send some data via a staging buffer and copy command to a buffer that is *only* visible to the host and *then* periodically modify some or all of that data (e.g. for deformable terrain) then that might be trickier, it's not something I have looked into.

EDIT: just seen the following post that might be related?  [Best way to store animated vertex data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44740106/best-way-to-store-animated-vertex-data?rq=1)

Comment: "*unmap the buffer*" Why unmap it?

Comment: @NicolBolas Good point, if you are continually updating the same buffer then there is no need to unmp.